# How to create a method which returns child's type, without generic type, in Dart?

Tags: generics, dart

I have two classes, a parent and a child, and the parent class have a method to return an instance of the child.

With generic type, I can do it like this:

```dart
import "dart:mirrors";

class Parent<T extends Parent> {
  T anotherMe() {
    var classMirror = reflectClass(this.runtimeType);
    var instance = classMirror.newInstance(new Symbol(""), []).reflectee;
    return instance;
  }
}

class Child extends Parent<Child> {
}
```

To test it, I write this code:

```dart
main() {
  Child child = new Child();
  var another = child.anotherMe();
  print(another);
}
```

Which prints:

```dart
Instance of 'Child'
```

But what if I don't want the `Parent` use generic type? E.g.:

```dart
class Parent {
    Type childType;
    Parent() {
        childType = this.runtimeType;
    }
    childType anotherMe() {
        var classMirror = reflectClass(this.runtimeType);
        var instance = classMirror.newInstance(new Symbol(""), []).reflectee;
        return instance;
    }
}
```

The code can't be compiled (of course), but you can get my idea. I ask this because I know scala has provided something like:

```dart
def anotherMe: this.type = {}
```

I found it useful sometimes, and wonder if I can do the same in Dart

Comment: Could you clarify what you are trying to do here? From what I read here, just drop the generic and declare the method as `Parent anotherMe()`, but I don't think that's what you mean?

Comment: `Parent anotherMe()` is not what I want, although it works since type system is optional in Dart. I want a way to refer to the child's type in parent, that the IDE may give some helps if it knows that

Comment: Parameter `T` also not help you in IDE because everything that IDE know about `T` is only that the >> 1) It is a `generic` parameter that may be know only at runtime 2) Only Information that you specify: `T extends Parent`. << So, `T` does not contains any information about all possible descendants because it declared in base class. If your declare it as `Parent anotherMe()` this would be not the same as you want but  this also would be not big difference because `T extends Parent` is practically same as `Parent` (any unknown descendant of Parent).

Comment: @Freewind After reading about this.type in Scala, I see why you would want to do that - sounds really comfortable. Unfortunately, I don't think you can comfortably recreate this behaviour in Dart. :-/